# Are API scripting commands embedded or created externally?

Tags: lua, scripting

I’m trying to use Lua/Moonsharp API scripting. There’s a command library, but there isn’t a function that I need. My question is, am I able to create my own function, or am I limited to what’s been written?

Specifically, for a software called BobCAD a Lua plugin is available. There are lists of commands like Bcc.SetCamObjParameter, though, there isn’t the command that I need. I’m assuming that some aspects of the BobCAD software are inaccessible to API, but am I limited to the library in this plugin, or can I add my own commands? I thought that there would be some C# file somewhere in the program directory where I can read the functions and possibly learn how to create my own, but I don’t see anything like that. (Or are scripting functions set up internally to the software, and I’m only given access to what has been provided?)

Answer (score 0):

(N.b. I'm not familiar with BobCAD specifically, but this answer should be generally applicable.)

Generally speaking, for use cases like this (where Lua scripting is provided as part of a larger program, or by a plugin for a larger program), it's the developer of the program or plugin who decides what API is available to Lua. In the latter case they may also be limited by what the program's plugin API allows; in the case of BobCAD you are likely limited to what the BobCAD plugin API permits, and then *further* limited by what parts of that API the developers of the Lua plugin chose to make available to Lua itself.

You can of course write your own functions in Lua, but in terms of actually talking to the host program you are restricted to the API that program makes available, unless they make available some mechanism (like LuaJIT's Foreign Function Interface) for reaching into the program from Lua and calling functions that were not made explicitly available -- which most do not.

As for finding "a C# file somewhere in the program directory" -- C# is a compiled language; C# libraries are generally shipped as pre-compiled CLR binaries (with a `.dll` extension) and do not contain source code. If the source code for BobCAD and/or the Lua plugin is available you could always modify it and re-compile it, but as BobCAD is commercial, closed-source software, I would not expect it to be available.

At that point, your options are basically:

- figure out a way to do what you need with the commands that are available;
- try to reverse engineer enough of the program to do what you need without access to the source code;
- or look for another program that has the features you need.